# Handle two html helpers for same property

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I am currently having two html helpers written for same property in my razor view.
first one is hidden and second one is visible.

Why I am having two controls is based on some business rules I will return text else html control.

The issue I am facing now is when I get a control back and user updates value in it, then its saving the value fine. 
But if he tries to save null, then its saving value from the hidden field. I am not able to figure out a workaround for this.

by the way I am using **form submit** and `toObject` to save the controls value

My html looks like below

```
<div style="display: none;">
    @Html.EditorFor(O => O.Prop)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.CustomHelper(O => O.prop)
</div>
```

Please help me with some work around.......

Comment: You sure what your claiming here. The `DefaultModelBinder` will always bind to the value of `Prop` to the value in the first helper (`@Html.EditorFor(O => O.Prop)`) and always ignore the value from `@Html.CustomHelper(O => O.prop)`. (unless you disable the first control so it does not post back). What do you mean _"your using toObject to save the controls value"_? You need to show your POST method. And what does `@Html.CustomHelper()` do?

Comment: why don't you approach it by using a `if(model.BusinessRule)`? that would be the most common way to do it.